# fullcalendar locale Uncaught TypeError: e.fullCalendar.datepickerLocale is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I implement a `fullCalendar` which is working fine, but as soon as I want to change the locale, I have the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.fullCalendar.datepickerLocale is not a function
```

Here is the JS code to configure the fullCalendar:

```
loadScript("js/plugin/fullcalendar/locale-all.js", "");
fullviewcalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: hdr,
                editable: true,
                droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
                locale: 'fr',
                drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                    // assign it the date that was reported
                    copiedEventObject.start = date;
                    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                    // render the event on the calendar
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                        $(this).remove();
                    }

                },

                select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                    if (title) {
                        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                                title: title,
                                start: start,
                                end: end,
                                allDay: allDay
                            }, true // make the event "stick"
                        );
                    }
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                }


            });
```

I'm using `jquery 1.12.4`, `jqueryui 1.12.`1 and `fullCalendar 3.1.0`, `moment 2.17.1`.

If I'm not loading the `local-all.js` script, my calendar is displayed correctly, but in English...

Do you have any idea why I get this error ?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/support/ "The latest version of FullCalendar is compatible with:
...
jQuery 2.0.0+
Moment 2.9.0+" I suggest you update your jQuery version to a supported one and then try again

Comment: I tried with jquery 3.1.1 but still the same error....

Comment: ok well it's still worth using the supported versions anyway. One more thing occurs to me. What is the loadScript function? Does it lazy load the script via ajax or something? Because if so, it will be asynchronous, and possibly the locale-all.js script has not fully finished loading when the `.fullCalendar` method runs, so maybe the locale code is not available. Try just declaring the script normally instead with a `<script>` tag and see if that helps

Comment: yes you were right, seems my scripts were not completely loaded before calling .fullCalendar. works fine by adding my scripts using simple <script> tag !

Comment: good news. I always wonder why people lazy load scripts, unless they have severe bandwidth issues in mobile apps or something. It just introduces another potential point of failure. Anyway I have added this as an answer for completeness, so if you are able to accept and/or upvote I would be grateful - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your loadScript function is lazy loading the script via ajax or something. If so, it will be asynchronous, and possibly the locale-all.js script has not fully finished loading when the .fullCalendar method runs, so maybe the locale code is not available.

Try just declaring the script normally instead with a `<script>` tag

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old post, but for future reference:

I just found out that this function was renamed from "Lang" to "Locale" in v3 of fullCalendar.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/lang

You can try to change the function `x.fullCalendar.datepickerLocale` to `x.fullCalendar.datepickerLang` or vice versa if you are having compatibility problems regarding v3+

Worked for me so hope it will work for others